# Can I get (la)tex to "keep register"?

Tags: tex-general

This is a general question about (La)Tex. Is it possible to configure/setup tex to make it "hold register"?

To "hold register" is to ensure that the horizontal lines which all "normal/plain" text is placed on, are the same on all pages.

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid-typesetting

Comment: I take that as a: No, not really.

Comment: It's a no, not _in general_ but for many classes of documents it can be set up to ensure that text stays on the grid, if you have lots of display math with stretchable space above and below then it's naturally more difficult.

Comment: context imho can hold register. So the general answer is yes. But at least in latex it is not easy: there are lot of spacings (around titles, in lists, around math etc) which need to be controlled.